# Decode JSON from received POST Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, post

I sent POST request to my web-server with a few JSON-Params within the params there is an array. I receive for in the POST array-variable:

```
$ids = $_POST['id_arr'];     // contains: [{\"id\":12},{\"id\":13}]
```

I don't know how to parse this to an array in PHP. I tried to solve it with json_decode, but it seems like the wrong way.

My desired result is this: `$ids = array(12, 13);`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the **json_decode** function to convert the objects to associative arrays. As shown in the [json_decode documentation](http://php.net/json_decode), this can be done by setting to *true* the second argument:

```
$ids = json_decode($_POST['id_arr'], true);
```

Comment: yes you are right. try like this :
`$id = '[{"id":12},{"id":13}]';`
`$res = json_decode($id, true);`
`print_r($res);`